# Dreamweaver undo/redo triggering upload to server

Tags: dreamweaver

I have a weird issue with Dreamweaver CC where if I press undo or redo a few times it seems to trigger the upload to server feature which in return asks me if I want to save the file before putting to the server.

I have restarted a number of times but this keeps happening.

I am running Windows 8.1 with all the updates and a fresh install of CC.

Has anyone else come across this and know of a solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I too had this problem.
I solved it by clicking on view and changing my view back and forth from code to live view and back to code.
Now it does not keep prompting for save on redo or undo